# phonegap build: Not receiving ios push notifications

Tags: ios, cordova, apple-push-notifications, phonegap-build

I have a simple phonegap app to test Push Notification. I use phonegap build to build the app and then install the app on my iphone using itunes. The registration of the push notification was successful with the production push certificate pem. But I couldn't receive any push notifications after executing the php script below. The script itself runs fine without any errors. Any ideas what could go wrong?

```
   // This this a fake device id:
$deviceToken = '9870h8v088bj29u080af894jj67klfgcv9mmm79k8e4l23456h908743n093e359';

// fake password:
$passphrase = '123456';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'New Message';
   ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
                           'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
                           $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
                     'alert' => $message,
                     'sound' => 'default',
                     'badge' => '1'
                     );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Comment: You say `The registration of the push notification was successful with the production push certificate` but you connect to sandbox server - `ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195`. Are you testing this in sandbox or production?

Comment: Thanks, I've also noticed that. It worked after I changed that to the production server.

Comment: @Vaeianor: I have same issue,  what is your solution? pls post here.

Comment: I was using a production certificate. The APNS server address should be:  gateway.push.apple.com:2195

Answer (score 1):

I have also gone through this problem but i have got the solution. To send the notifications to device You have to enable the 2195 port in firewall. Just conatct your server company to enable this port. I have server from hostgator i called them they enabled the port and now working fine.